# Why child div is not coming in boundary of parent div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a very simple HTML/CSS code, which has parent div `pageWrapper`, inside that I have, `header`, `rightPanel`. I have boundary to `pageWrapper`, so `header`, and `rightPanel` both should be shown inside boundary.

When I see HTML rendering in Visual Studio designer window, it shows correct output, rightPanel does come under border. But in IE/Chrome/Firefox, `rightPanel` is not coming in boundary of `pageWrapper`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #pageWrapper {
            font: 14px/11.4;
            width: 1000px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
          border: 5px solid black;
        }

        #header {
            height: 127px;
            width: 1000px;
        }

        #logo {
            position: relative;
            left: 15px;
            top: 4px;
        }

        #blogSlogan {
            position: relative;
            width: 270px;
            left: 685px;
            top: -125px;
        }

        #searchBox {
            position: relative;
            left: 685px;
            top: -70px;
            width: 290px;
        }

        #rightPanel {
            position:relative;
            background-color: red;
            height: 600px;
            width: 500px;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pageWrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <img src="Images/linkedin.jpg" alt="Social voice logo"
                height="109px" id="logo" />
            <p id="blogSlogan">Your source for mobile/media marketing.</p>
            <div id="searchBox">
                <input type="text" name="search" size="25" value="Search" />
                <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End header-->

        <div id="rightPanel">

        </div>
        <!-- End rightPanel-->
    </div>
    <!-- End pageWrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Use any css reset and check problem solved or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have floated the right panel, yet there's nothing after it to clear the float.

I'd consider reading a bit more about [using floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

You need to add the following:

```
 #pageWrapper:after {
     clear: both;
     content: " ";
     display: block;
     visibility: hidden; 
     height: 0; 
 }
```

Or if you need to support lower than IE8 (`:after` isn't supported) , then you'll need to add an additional `div` after your floated elements and make sure it has the CSS `clear: both;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6a5at5p/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is very simple. You applied a `float:right` to your red div, but its container does not float. This generates the behaviour you see, as per box model specifications.

You should take some time to understand how box model works, how the different values of `position` and `float` affect your style, as I see you used some position:relative and it actually doesn't make any sense looking at the rest of the html and css.

Comment: I am very new to HTML/CSS. Thanks for advice. Can you suggest link where I can learn HTML/CSS quickly. +1.

Comment: There is no quickly. You can learn but it will take time and practice as for anything else. You can start by doing the tutorials on w3schools and html5doctor and then google for more advanced guides.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `#rightpanel` float CSS property to `right` it will be pulled out of the HTML flow. You need to add an element at the end of `#pageWrapper` with the CSS property `clear: both` so it makes the main div extend to the point where all the floated elements end. The cleaner way to do this with CSS  is adding this lines to your CSS:

```
#pageWrapper:after {
  content: “ ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add overflow:hidden property to the parent div you will have your answer 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change the right panel from float right to right:500px; will work

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>dd</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #pageWrapper {
            font: 14px/11.4;
            width: 1000px;

            background-color: #FFF;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
          border: 5px solid black;
        }

        #header {
            height: 127px;
            width: 1000px;
        }

        #logo {
            position: relative;
            left: 15px;
            top: 4px;
        }

        #blogSlogan {
            position: relative;
            width: 270px;
            left: 685px;
            top: -125px;
        }

        #searchBox {
            position: relative;
            left: 685px;
            top: -70px;
            width: 290px;
        }

        #rightPanel {
            position:relative;
            background-color: red;
            height: 600px;
            width: 500px;
            right:-500px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pageWrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <img src="Images/linkedin.jpg" alt="Social voice logo"
                height="109px" id="logo" />
            <p id="blogSlogan">Your source for mobile/media marketing.</p>
            <div id="searchBox">
                <input type="text" name="search" size="25" value="Search" />
                <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End header-->

        <div id="rightPanel">

        </div>
        <!-- End rightPanel-->
    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your html and css

```
<body>
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <div class="secondWrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="Images/linkedin.jpg" alt="Social voice logo"
            height="109px" id="logo" />
        <p id="blogSlogan">Your source for mobile/media marketing.</p>
        <div id="searchBox">
            <input type="text" name="search" size="25" value="Search" />
            <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End header-->

    <div id="rightPanel">

    </div>
    <!-- End rightPanel-->
    </div> <!-- End secondwrapper-->
</div>
<!-- End pageWrapper-->

</body>
```

What i did is included another wrapper inside pagewrapper and given float and border

here is css

```
    #pageWrapper {
        font: 14px/11.4;
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;


    }
 .secondWrapper{
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width:100%:

 }

    #header {
        height: 127px;
        width: 1000px;
        float:left;
    }

    #logo {
        float:left;
        margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    }

    #blogSlogan {
       float:right;
        width: 270px;

    }

    #searchBox {
        float:right;
        clear:right;

    }

    #rightPanel {
        background-color: red;
        height: 600px;
        width: 500px;
        float: right;
    }
```